# JSON API Parsing Issue

Tags: java, json, api, retrofit, jsonparser

I created a GUI that lists the highest and lowest rated movies listed in the Hydra Movies Database API. When I parse through it to find the max and min IMDB ratings using Compare.Comparing and parseInt I get a numbers format exception. I changed the max to parseDouble just to see if that would help and I got a null pointer exception.

I'm putting the code and errors that are specifically relevant but if you'd like a better full picture here is the link to the project on GitHub:
https://github.com/scohen40/cohen-mcw152-MovieDatabaseJSON/tree/bugFixing/src/movieDatabaseApp/movie

Here's the code for my controller:

```
package movieDatabaseApp.movie;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class MovieController {


    private MovieView view;
    private MovieService service;

    @Inject
    public
    MovieController(MovieView view, MovieService service) {
        this.view = view;
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void refreshData() {
        requestHighest2018();
        requestLowest2018();
    }

    public void requestHighest2018() {
        requestHighestMovies(service.getAllMovies(),
//      requestHighestMovies(service.getMovies2018(),
                view.gethTitleField(),
                view.gethYearField(),
                view.gethRatingField(),
                view.gethLanguageField());          
    }
    void requestLowest2018() {
        requestLowestMovies(service.getAllMovies(),
//      requestLowestMovies(service.getMovies2018(),
                view.getlTitleField(),
                view.getlYearField(),
                view.getlRatingField(),
                view.getlLanguageField());          
    }




    private void requestHighestMovies(Call<List<Movie>> call,
        JTextComponent title,
        JTextComponent year,
        JTextComponent rating,
        JTextComponent language) 
    {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Movie>> call, Response<List<Movie>> response) {
                List<Movie> list = response.body();

                showHighest(list, title, year, rating, language);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Movie>> arg0, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

        });

    }

    private void requestLowestMovies(Call<List<Movie>> call,
            JTextComponent title,
            JTextComponent year,
            JTextComponent rating,
            JTextComponent language) 
        {
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Movie>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Movie>> call, Response<List<Movie>> response) {
                    List<Movie> list = response.body();

                    showLowest(list, title, year, rating, language);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Movie>> arg0, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }

            });

        }

    public void showHighest(List<Movie> list,
            JTextComponent title,
            JTextComponent year,
            JTextComponent rating,
            JTextComponent language) 
    {
        Optional<Movie> highest = list.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> Double.parseDouble(e.getImdb_rating())));

        title.setText(String.valueOf(highest.get().getTitle()));
        year.setText(String.valueOf(highest.get().getMovie_year()));
        rating.setText(String.valueOf(highest.get().getImdb_rating()));
        language.setText(String.valueOf(highest.get().getLanguage()));
    }

    void showLowest(List<Movie> list,
            JTextComponent title,
            JTextComponent year,
            JTextComponent rating,
            JTextComponent language) 
    {
        Optional<Movie> lowest = list.stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparing(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getImdb_rating())));

        title.setText(String.valueOf(lowest.get().getTitle()));
        year.setText(String.valueOf(lowest.get().getMovie_year()));
        rating.setText(String.valueOf(lowest.get().getImdb_rating()));
        language.setText(String.valueOf(lowest.get().getMovie_year()));
    }

}
```

Here's the error that I got with the max parinsing as double and the min as int:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)

at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)

at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)

at movieDatabaseApp.movie.MovieController.lambda$0(MovieController.java:109)

at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparingDouble$8dcf42ea$1(Comparator.java:532)

at java.util.function.BinaryOperator.lambda$maxBy$1(BinaryOperator.java:74)

at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$2ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:123)

at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)

at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)

at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:479)

at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.max(ReferencePipeline.java:515)

at movieDatabaseApp.movie.MovieController.showHighest(MovieController.java:109)

at movieDatabaseApp.movie.MovieController$1.onResponse(MovieController.java:65)

at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:123)

at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)

at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7.4"

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

at movieDatabaseApp.movie.MovieController.lambda$1(MovieController.java:124)

at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)

at java.util.function.BinaryOperator.lambda$minBy$0(BinaryOperator.java:59)

at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$2ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:123)

at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)

at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)

at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)

at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:479)

at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.min(ReferencePipeline.java:520)

at movieDatabaseApp.movie.MovieController.showLowest(MovieController.java:124)

at movieDatabaseApp.movie.MovieController$2.onResponse(MovieController.java:89)

at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:123)

at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)

at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm pretty new with JSON API integration and so I don't really know what errors on the topic mean or what is normal to look out for yet. Any help would be appreciated.

ALSO - here is the original JSON that is being parsed through, if you'd like to see it: https://hydramovies.com/api-v2/?source=http://hydramovies.com/api-v2/current-Movie-Data.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I ended up switching the data type of the imdb_ratings from String to Double and taking out both the filters and the parsers. 
Now it works!

You can look through it on my GitHub listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this error has anything to do with JSON as such. You get NPE or NFE because one or more movies in your list don't have IMDB ratings or the rating are there with decimals in it which can't be integer parsable,

Comment: So I actually thought that that might be the problem, so I tried switching rating to runtime, but I still had the same problem :/ I got NPEs

Comment: At one place, you have Integer.parseInt which fails becuase of "7.4" being passed. At other place, you have Double.parseDouble which fails becuase of null being passed. Try using Double.parseDouble at both places and handle NULL explicitly. May be like this - list.stream().filter(a-> a !=null).max(........

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at movieDatabaseApp.movie.MovieController.lambda$1(MovieController.java:109)
 at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparingDouble$8dcf42ea$1(Comparator.java:532)
 at java.util.function.BinaryOperator.lambda$maxBy$1(BinaryOperator.java:74)
 at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$2ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:123)
 at

Comment: I'm sure you have either one of hte movie instances pointing to NULL or getImdb_String on it returns NULL. Use the traditional FOR loop and print all the IMDB ratings :) - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

Comment: I'm sure there probably is, but if I filtered them out as you suggested, why would I still be getting an exception? Am I just not doing it right?   Optional<Movie> highest = list.stream().filter(e -> e!=null)
    .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> Double.parseDouble(e.getImdb_rating())));